# Torah Commentary of R. Isaac Samuel Reggio

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, acharonim

Is the commentary of [R. Isaac Samuel Reggio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Samuel_Reggio) on the Torah available for free online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are links to: [Bereshith](https://books.google.com/books?id=j_FuC1T5nzwC&pg=PT6&dq=%22%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D%22%20%22%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI0reLyPLQAhUY22MKHb-dCOYQ6AEITzAH#v=onepage&q&f=false), [Shemos](https://books.google.com/books?id=TLpAAQAAMAAJ&dq=%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D&pg=PT5#v=onepage&q&f=false), [Vayikra](https://books.google.com/books?id=XhdEAQAAMAAJ&dq=%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D&pg=PR6#v=onepage&q&f=false), [Bamidbar](https://books.google.com/books?id=G7pAAQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions:JnHXXXJk8coC&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju74eHyvLQAhVG4mMKHYpNCKoQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [Devarim](https://books.google.com/books?id=DnoQAAAAYAAJ&dq=%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D&pg=PR4#v=onepage&q&f=false) on Google Books.

Comment: I only regret that I have but one upvote to give for your answer. I already upvoted and marked correct, so there is no more recognition I can give to this fine addition to your fine answer. Thanks.

Comment: FYI a new edition of all 5 volumes was reprinted a couple years ago.

Answer (score 3):

[Leviticus is available on `hebrewbooks.org`.](http://hebrewbooks.org/19118) (The listed date there, שנה/‎1595, is a mistake.)